# Testing to see whether a navigation property can retrieve values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following code attempts to retrieve an object which is a navigation property for a disconnected graph.

If the property is not loaded an error occurs

> *The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be
>   used for operations that require a connection*

Is there a way that I can test whether the property is loaded ?

```
navProps = GetNavigationProperties(originalEntity);
foreach (PropertyInfo navProp in navProps)
{
   object obj = navProp.GetValue(item);  // fails if the property type is an unloaded collection
   // more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868996/permanently-disable-configuration-proxycreationenabled-in-ef)  helped me.
I found that if I included

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

in the constructor to my context then  navProp.GetValue(item) returns null instead of raising an error