# Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false Location?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `WebAPI` which calls functions from a `Class Library` which calls data from a `Entity Framework Model First Class Library`.

I am suffering from the dreaded "self referencing loop detected"

So, in my `DataStore` class library I have the `autogenerated` Context:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace SADatastore
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class SADatastoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public SADatastoreEntities()
        : base("name=SADatastoreEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DB> DBS { get; set; }
    ....
    }
}
```

I then have a `Connections.cs` file which I user to pass the `connection string` into the `context` with...

```
public partial class SADatastoreEntities
{
    public SADatastoreEntities(string connStr)
        : base(string.Format(@"metadata=res://*/SAModel.csdl|res://*/SAModel.ssdl|res://*/SAModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='{0}'", connStr))
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868996/permanently-disable-configuration-proxycreationenabled-in-ef
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code I am attempting to set `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` which is what I have read should solve my problem. But it has no effect.

In my API I have the following controller

```
public class SA_GetAllItemDetailsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("SA_GetAllItemDetails")]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<SA_Items> Get(DateTime? lastUpdated = null, int limit = 100, int offset = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Helpers.Authorise(Request, "WriteVisitors").Authorised)
            {

                List<SA_Items> result = new List<SA_Items>();

                result = SADatastoreEngine.Functions.Item.SA_GetAllItemDetails(
                    Settings.Default.ConnectionString,
                    lastUpdated,
                    limit,
                    offset
                    );

                // conver the result to a string to have a look at it
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondNotAuthorised());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondWithAnError(e));
        }
    }
}
public class SA_GetItemByItemIdController : ApiController
{
    [Route("SA_GetItemByItemId/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public SA_Items Get(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Helpers.Authorise(Request, "WriteVisitors").Authorised)
                return SADatastoreEngine.Functions.Item.GetItemByItemId(Settings.Default.ConnectionString, id);
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondNotAuthorised());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondWithAnError(e));
        }
    }
}
public class SA_CreateItemController : ApiController
{
    [Route("SA_CreateItem")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateViewModel]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Post(SA_Items item)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the auth details
            AuthorisationModel auth = Helpers.Authorise(Request, "WriteVisitors");

            if (Helpers.Authorise(Request, "WriteVisitors").Authorised)
            {
                return SADatastoreEngine.Functions.Item.CreateItem(Settings.Default.ConnectionString, auth.DBSId, item);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondNotAuthorised());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondWithAnError(e));
        }
    }
}
public class SA_UpdateItemController : ApiController
{
    [Route("SA_UpdateItem")]
    [HttpPut]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Post(SA_Items item)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the auth details
            AuthorisationModel auth = Helpers.Authorise(Request, "WriteVisitors");

            if (auth.Authorised)
            {
                return SADatastoreEngine.Functions.Item.UpdateItem(Settings.Default.ConnectionString, auth.DBSId, item);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondNotAuthorised());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Helpers.RespondWithAnError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `SA_GetAllItemDetails` function:

```
public static List<SA_Items> SA_GetAllItemDetails(string connStr, DateTime? lastUpdated, int limit, int offset) {
        using (SADatastoreEntities db = new SADatastoreEntities(connStr)) {
            if (lastUpdated == null)
                lastUpdated = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

            return db.SA_Items
                .Include("SA_Model")
                .Include("SA_Model.SA_Manufacturers")
                .Where(x => x.LastUpdated > lastUpdated)
                .OrderBy(x => x.ItemID)
                .Skip(offset)
                .Take(limit)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

I have added a line where I am attempting to convert the object to a json string so I can see it. But this is where it throws the error.

I have the feeling the setting

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

is being ignored because it's in the wrong location. But I cannot work out where it should be.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong please?

EDIT

I have now changed my code to attempt to serialize it:

```
JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
      ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};

// convert the result to a string to have a look at it
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented, _jsonSettings);
```

which leads to a Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown error

Comment: So what's inside that SADatastoreEngine.Functions.Item.SA_GetAllItemDetails ?

Comment: @Evk added that code... sorry

Comment: `SA_GetAllItemDetails` doesn't suffer from this problem but if you ever use `public SADatastoreEntities() : base("name=SADatastoreEntities")` you'll get the wrong behaviour - I think you intended to call `this("name=...")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in `Include`s. When you retrieve `SA_Items` you include `SA_Model` which most likely has back reference to `SA_Item`. Because that `SA_Item` is already tracked by context (you make a query for them) - there is no need to use lazy loading or create any proxies to fill that back reference. In result, every `SA_Item` has reference to `SA_Model` which in turn has back reference to `SA_Item` no matter of `LazyLoadingEnabled` or `ProxyCreationEnabled` (because reference is already tracked by context).

You cannot prevent loading of that back references, so you have to manually check for loops when serializing.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. How do you mean "you have to manually check for loops when serializing" I am using Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: @TrevorDaniel for example by using ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: In my API I already have _config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; That has no effect either :(

Comment: I don't see you pass any settings to JsonConvert in your example. Are you sure those settings from your config are indeed applied?. As far as I remember you need to use JsonConvert.DefaultSettings for that.

Comment: That could be the problem. That line appears to have no effect. I will need to look at what you mean by JsonConvert.DefaultSettings

Comment: First try to pass settings explicitly to JsonConvert.SerializeObject which produces that loop error. If that resolves the problem you can see where is the problem with your current setup.

Comment: I get Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: Are you use you use ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore and not ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize? Works fine for me in your case with ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore.

Comment: yes. Just added my code to the question... (thanks for your help with this)

Comment: Can't help anymore unfortunately, because cannot reproduce at this point (ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore works for me).